# Upload a zip file to S3 in Clojure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clojure

I want to upload zip files to S3. I'm not able to find any resources for this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Perhaps: [GitHub - mcohen01/amazonica: A comprehensive Clojure client for the entire Amazon AWS api.](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica#s3)

Comment: see if raw restful call applicable?

Comment: I tried but it's not working, I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Cognitect's [`aws-api`](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api) is a pure Clojure library for accessing AWS services. It is built on the service API data specifications published by AWS, rather than wrapping the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) (as done by the [Amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica) library, for example).

The action to upload a file to an S3 bucket is [`PutObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html), there are [a couple of simple examples](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api/blob/1c72ae1efadb8915846ffc9b83360d94c397fa6d/examples/s3_examples.clj#L58) showing its use in `aws-api`.

Comment: Do you have any working sample programs? I tried running from there but it's not working.

Comment: What [response](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api#responses-success-failure) or stack trace are you getting? How are you [providing the AWS credentials](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api#credentials) and [region](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api#region-lookup) when setting up the client? Using the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_REGION` is the easiest method to get going.

Comment: Below Error, I'm getting.
Syntax error (FileNotFoundException) compiling at (s3.clj:1:1).
Could not locate cognitect/aws/client/api__init.class, cognitect/aws/client/api.clj or cognitect/aws/client/api.cljc on classpath.

Comment: Please see the [instructions on dependencies to include](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api#deps) in your project. That error indicates you are missing at least `com.cognitect.aws/api`. Be sure to include `com.cognitect.aws/endpoints` too.